# Need to create a mouse over help icon

Tags: javascript

Icon needs to display a message when you mouse over and the message becomes hidden when you mouse out. Plain javascript please

```
<img src="helpicon.png" width=50 height=50 onmouseover="mytoolTip('Click a form field to see its requirements.');" onmouseout="mytoolTip('');"  />

function mytoolTip(ValueToDisplay)
{ 
document.getElementById("helpicon").innerHTML = ValueToDisplay;

}
```

Comment: You can use title attribute instead:

<img src="helpicon.png" width=50 height=50 title="Click a form field to see its requirements."/>

When hovering, you will see the text appear, no need to use JS.

Comment: Where do you want to display the message? I saw you try to get the selector `helpicon`, but it's not in your code. Also, your HTML codes are quite messy. Attribute values should be surrounded by quotes, and `alt` attribute is missing.

Comment: @ThanNgoHoai aw man, if I saw your comment I wouldn't have posted my answer, damn I spent too much time on the snippet.

Comment: So you will go with the Title Attribute? :)

Comment: Hi @JasminKenjar if any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use the HTML5  `title`  attribute. e.g.

```css
#myBigFatDiv {
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBigFatDiv" title="Hell Yea it is!">Hover over me to find out if this is a great answer</div>
```

Comment: Is it a kind of a joke ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette OP wanted a tooltip, I gave him a tooltip

Comment: I thought I was drunk. Cheers!

Comment: `title` attribute is **not** HTML5-specific. It exists in much much earlier HTML specification.

Comment: @Raptor Yes it is true that it existed before html5, but it was not supported on all elements until html5; it wasn't a global attribute until now. That's the only reason I specified html5.

Answer (score 1):

There is no element with `id` `helpicon` in your html. Try adding an element with the id and give it a shot!

Something like:

```
<img src="helpicon.png" width="50" height="50" onmouseover="mytoolTip('Click a form field to see its requirements.')" onmouseout="mytoolTip('')">
<p id="helpicon"></p>
```

Comment: This is actually the better answer

Comment: For HTML tidiness sake, don't mix up the use of double quotes, single quotes and no quotes in same HTML. Also, inline `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` are not suggested in modern HTML.